# Using session variable in another session grails 2.4.2

Tags: grails, authentication, session-variables

I am using grails 2.4.2 and I want to use session value from another session is this possible ? case is :
i have a user when user is logged in and updates his profile then super admin will get notification for updated profile. For that purpose I have set variable as

```
 String notification = session.count
 session.count =Integer.parseInt(notification) + verify
```

where verify is the value of the updated profile 
Now when superadmin is logged in I want to get the `session.count` variable at the menu page is this possible without using `session filters` how?

Comment: `Services` are `singletons` by default, which means you should be able to leverage that in a way that you are describing.  Just store these variables in your own made up `service`, this will allow the individual users to modify the variable and the admin to see those values.  You'll have to play with it to see if it does what you are looking for.

http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Services/Usage.html

Answer (score 1):

No, the `sessions` are isolated. If you want to access the state set by one user from the session of another one, you have to use a more or less persistent storage:

You could store your vars in a DB or use a `service` with a e.g. `ConcurrentHashMap`:

```
class CrossContextService {
  ConcurrentHashMap cache
}

class SomeController{
  def crossContextService
  def someAction(){
    crossContextService.cache.count = ...
  }
}
```